# Whitelisting Ionic app in Salesforce Org for CORS/CSP

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cors, salesforce, content-security-policy

We are trying to integrate the Salesforce Embedded Messaging widget into my ionic cordova application.

```
Ionic CLI                     : 6.17.1 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.9.4
@angular/cli                  : 11.1.2

Cordova:

Cordova CLI                   : 10.0.0 (cordova-lib@10.1.0)
Cordova Platforms             : android 10.1.2, browser 6.0.0, ios 6.3.0
```

Ionic application locally runs on `http:/localhost:8101` so we whitelisted it on Salesforce and it worked well for both IOS and Android.

On production, the Ionic app has the hostnames as these:

```
IOS ==> ionic://localhost
Android ==> http://localhost
```

**Problem:**
Salesforce doesn't allow whitelisting any origin except with HTTP/HTTPS protocol. Ionic doesn't allow to use HTTP/HTTPS scheme for IOS ([details here](https://www.mathew-paul.nz/posts/cordova-webview-schemes-and-protocols/)). That means we can not whitelist the widget iframe for ionic IOS.

**Tried Solution**
To bypass CORS in IOS, I hosted the proxy server [cors-anywhere](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors-anywhere) and used it in an `XMLHttpRequest` interceptor on the client side. It works and downloads all the widget-related files.

Unfortunately, the widget still doesn't work because of the `Content Security Policy directive`

```
Refused to frame 'https://example.com' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors http://localhost http://localhost:8101".
```

Is there any way we can get out of this debacle by:

- whitelisting `ionic://localhost` in Salesforce?
- Bypassing CSP on the client side?
- Or any other way?